# router.register default POST method writes empty value to postgres DB

Tags: python, postgresql, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a python project setup with Django 1.8.0 and POSTGRESQL. My model look like this:

```
  class poll_db(models.Model):
      p_pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      p_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
      p_desc = models.CharField(max_length=512)
```

I have a post url registered to router on urls.py:

```
    router.register(r'newpoll', views.createPoll)
```

I am trying to make a default POST call with the following URL

http://localhost:8080/newpoll/

And my postBody looks like:

```
  {
      "name": "What's the weekend plan?",
      "desc": "Poll to decide on the weekend plan"
  }
```

The request hits the server and there is a new entry created on the DB. But when I look at the created entry, it has empty values except for the p_pk

```
    14 |                  |
```

which means the values are passed as empty. But when I try to override the default create method on the views.py, I see the values as part of the request and add to the db is fine.

All I am trying is to skip writing a method for adding it to the DB and use the default create method.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you show your serializer ?

Comment: `p_name` and `name` in post?

Comment: @BearBrown Since the `CharField` is not defined with `null=True`, he can't create a new entry with empty values, right?

Comment: @JPG yes, you're right, so i think the question is not correct.

Comment: Please provide views & serializers

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I had read-only fields on serializer.